# SublimeText3: keyboard shortcut percent covered

Tags: code-coverage, sublimetext, maven-plugin, shortcut

there is a short cut to show the percent of code coverage for apex class?

Equival to: MavensMate>UnitTesting>Show Test Coverage for this Apex class/trigger

Thanks,

Lili

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the [`MavensMate`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MavensMate) plugin for Sublime Text 3. There is no built-in keyboard shortcut, but `"MavensMate: Get Apex Code Coverage For This Apex Class"` is available from the Command Palette. The command is called `get_apex_code_coverage`, so you can [create your own key binding](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/customization/key_bindings.html) if you wish.